# How can I model a complex tree syntax with different types of nodes using enums in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust, enums, abstract-syntax-tree

**Context**

I was exploring rust language by trying to write a rudimentary JS engine. I stumbled upon [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/tree/master/acorn) which gives AST output in [ESTree](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es5.md#statements) format.

Example output for `1;` is:

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 3,
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ExpressionStatement",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 2,
      "expression": {
        "type": "Literal",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 1,
        "value": 1,
        "raw": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "script"
}
```

Now, I wanted to model this JSON as an AST in rust and that is where I am not sure how to proceed.

The root node in JSON as well as children nodes are `Node`s which can either have `type=Program` or `type=Statement`. `type=Statement` furthermore is `type=ExpressionStatement` but can be other types of `type=Statement`s too.

My first attempt was to model it 1-to-1 as a `struct` in rust. But I feel `enum`s is a better type here according to me because:

1. `type` field in ESTree JSON can be converted to a `Program` or `ExpressionStatement` making `type` redundant and saving actual space.
2. Removing `type` field and being more expressive through types leaves less scope of validation errors too.

**Actual Problem**

I wanted something like:

```
struct Node {
    start: Option<usize>,
    end: Option<usize>
}

struct Program {
    ...Node,
    body: Vec<DirectiveOrStatement>;
}

enum DirectiveOrStatement {
    Statement {
        ...Node
    },
    ExpressionStatement {
        ...Statement,
        expression: Expression
    }

}
```

But this is an obvious syntax error in rust. How can I make sure I am not duplicating `start` and `end` fields in each and every enum branch and somehow utilize fields written in one struct in another?

Is what i am attempting possible and, if yes, how to achieve it best? Thank you! I am new to rust and unable to find prior art on this one.

Comment: It seems serde's [Struct flattening](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html) should solve your problem.

Comment: I don't grasp what your Rust code is supposed to do, even if it were syntactically valid. What does `...` mean? Is this supposed to be like inheritance?

Comment: You can sometimes use generics to replace class hierarchies; maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e85d257ce95f665a0eb9c6909121bdf8)

Comment: I would define a `struct Node` that contains the `start` and `end` fields plus a `contents` field that is an `enum` for the variable part.